# Question regarding Induction On Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove by induction for finite sets that $|m*n|=|m|*|n|$. This question involves proving the statement through inductive steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to ask for clarification of what you mean by mn, but here I am going to assume that you mean the Cartesian product between M and N. We can prove this by induction on N.

For $|N| = 0$, N is the empty set, then $M$ X $N$ is the empty set. So, in this case, we have $|MN| = 0 = |M||N| $.

For $|N| = 1, $ $N = \{x\}$, for some element x, then the cartesian product is $MN = \{(m;x) | m \in M\}$. We have a clear bijection between M and $MN$ $m \rightarrow (m,n)$. So, $|MN| = |M| = |M||N|$. 
Now, argue by induction that $|MN| = |M| |N|$ for a given $|N| = n$

If $|N| = n+1$, then let $x \in N$. Then, $N = \{x\} \cup  X$, where $|X| = n$, then
$MN = M(\{x\} \cup N) = M\{x\} \cup MN$. Note that  $M\{x\}$ and $MX$ are disjoint, so that the cardinality becomes $|MN|$ = $|M\{x\}| + |MX|$. Use induction hypothesis to get that $|MN| = m (n + 1)$, finishing the proof.

Comment: If you don't understand something, do not hesitate to ask. I see you are new user. My suggestion is that you should show some attempt on resolving this problem, then you will not risk being downvoted. Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: I am new to StackExchange. Sorry for not going with the rules and regulations. Cezar98 thanks for the response. Im inviting my friends on the discussion so we resolve this problem :).

Comment: No problem. Everybody was new at some point. Just, try to show what you have done in the future, even if you think it is totally wrong.